# What are the major branches or areas of feminist thought?

Tags: feminism

I'm becoming interested in delving further into feminist philosophy and have come to understand that 'feminism' actually represents an incredibly rich and diverse set of thought.

So what I wonder is if feminist thought can be categorized into major branches or major theoretical concepts, and if so, what those concepts are?

Comment: You find a lot of entries concerning feminist aspects of different branches of philosophy at http://plato.stanford.edu/

Comment: Theories of moral intuition are sometimes called feminist by one of my lecturers, but interesting enough, a fast google search (SPE, Wiki) did not spit out a single woman writing on that theme. As I know she mentioned some, there's work to be done from a feminist point of view. Ironic, isn't it? Martha Nussbaum is surely one exponent, though.

Comment: Trust me, there is no "feminist thought" -- *except as she tells you herself*.

Answer (score -1):

Feminism is many things, but if you are referring to modern day feminism it is based on the idea that all people should be equal, specifically referring to sexism. As far as major branches go, There are near endless categories of feminism with none necessarily more prominent than any others. Hope this helps.

Comment: There are at least three main groups that call themselves "feminists" and none of them define themselves in terms of "sexism." One group is concerned with giving women the same sort of autonomy with men. Two are concerned with accomplishing equality through different means...